# Delete specific file

Tags: c#, system.io.file

Can you suggest some codes, how to delete a specific file when I search the zip code to delete it, the file that already saved will be deleted if I click the button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string EmployeeData = File.ReadAllText("Employee.txt");
        if (EmployeeData.Contains(textDelete.Text))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(EmployeeData);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
    }  
}
```

Comment: System.IO.File.Delete(Employee.txt) should work. Your code now searches for the content/text of the file and wants to delete that one.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Can you show a list of files, an example of search data and Employee.txt contents and what should happen when someone types in something?

Comment: Take care that if the `textDelete.Text` is empty, then `string.Contains` will always return true.

Comment: if this is the output..

Warren
Step
48492995
Philippines
7000  //

Praisey
Cruz
48795955
New Zealand
8000

and if I search the zip code.. the data with those zip code will be deleted and the data with different zip code will not be deleted

Comment: So you don't want to delete the file, but you want to remove a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.. and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) is the documentation for your reference.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    try
    {
        string EmployeeData = File.ReadAllText("Employee.txt");
        if (EmployeeData.Contains(textDelete.Text))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath("Employee.txt"));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
    }  
}
```

On the safer side, you should first check if file exist or not.. use `File.Exists` method to make sure that file exist and only then perform the read/delete operation on file. You should avoid `known exceptions`. Use below code..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(@"Employee.txt"))
        {
            string EmployeeData = File.ReadAllText("Employee.txt");
            if (EmployeeData.Contains(textDelete.Text))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath("Employee.txt"));
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code for doing it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string _path = "Employee.txt";
        string EmployeeData = File.ReadAllText(_path);
        if (EmployeeData.Contains(textDelete.Text))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(_path));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Declaring a variable with name path doesn't mean it will get the file path. You would need to read the path.